# Content rating removed- Your app content rating was removed. Please submit a new content rating questionnaire before publishing updates to your app

Tags: google-play

i have got this message in google play developer account for my app

Content rating removed
Your app content rating was removed. Please submit a new content rating questionnaire before publishing updates to your app.

Some information about your app is incomplete.

and now I am not able to update app.

### Below is the mail content that I got from google play team :

This is a notification that the content rating of your application,  , with package ID xxx.xxxx, has been changed to UNRATED. Unrated apps may not be visible to users who use content filtering on the Play Store.

REASON FOR CONTENT RATING CHANGE: Violation of the Google Play content rating policy.

These guidelines apply to all content in your app, including user generated content, in-app products, and advertisements.

After a regular review, we’ve determined that your app has an inaccurate content rating. Please retake the content rating questionnaire for your app and submit an update.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, you can submit an appeal on the Google Play Help Center.

We appreciate your help with ensuring an accurate content rating experience for Google Play users.

The Google Play Team

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It is a vendor support question about a specific account/application which should be addressed to the vendor directly. (It also contains a clear statement of what the problem is and what to do to resolve it.)

Comment: Did you try re-submitting the content rating questionaire before trying to update your app?

Comment: @KenWhite I don't think it is quite that binary, this may not be considered off-topic as it is could be considered "software tools commonly used by programmers" which is defined as acceptable in the help center.  It's certainly not a good question as it shows no research effort, however...

Comment: @user700390: No, it's not a "software tool". It's an app/account specific problem, and there is no information here that is of general public use. Any issue with the app will be app-specific, and the error message is quite clear and self-explanatory. In this case, it *is* quite binary - the only ones who can explain any specific problem with this app are the support staff for Google Play, who would need access to this specific user/company account. It's clearly a customer-specific question that can only be answered by the vendor's support staff, and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: @KenWhite I've flagged similar questions in the past and they have always been disputed.  I certainly don't disagree that this is a poor question, but I don't see which of the "off-topic" close flags would apply here.  The general response I see on meta about these kind of questions is that they should be down-voted and not flagged.  Which "off-topic" close flag did you choose?

Comment: @user700390: I cast a close vote as off-topic with a custom reason (which you can read in my original comment here). The problem is specific to this app; the solution is a specific action that only this user can take (and that is clearly described in the email), and the action to take if they want to appeal is to submit that appeal on the Google Play Help Center (which is not StackOverflow). There is zero to be done here, and zero that is useful to anyone other than this user.

Answer (score 0):

I had something simmilar(got rejected 4-5 times with same message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653430/google-play-rejection-with-violation-of-the-google-play-content-rating-policy) in the end I think that they think the pegi rate you got is to low to your app.. so try to answer questions even if it wrongs just to get higher pegi rate.. but still be careful what you choose..